# IIS Application requires Forms Authentication for everything

Tags: iis, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc

At the moment, I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET MVC application using a local IIS server (Dev Server was just too slow). However, every page request, including CSS/JS results in a redirect to the login page.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Check every parent folder of your application for web.config files that contain something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" ...></forms>
</authentication>
```